# Como lograr que una funcion float retorne null

Tags: java

lo que quiero hacer es  una funcion float la cual se encargara de hacer una división de 2 números, pero al momento de recibir una división por 0 esta me retornara un 0 como respuesta , no se si sea posible que me retorne un NaN o un null, y como obtenerlo.

```
 public float division(){  
          num1=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el primer numero"));;
           num2=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el segundo numero"));;
           if (num2==0){
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error, no se puede dividir entre 0 ","Resultado",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
              }else{
                 resultado=num1/num2;
           }


       return resultado;
   }
```

Comment: Si deseas que un método no retorne algo entonces me parece que el camino es por `void`, por otro lado si deseas una respuesta en caso de que se trate de hacer una división por 0 entonces me parece que el camino es `try/catch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

float no puede devolver null por que es un tipo de dato primitivo y su valor por defecto es 0.0, lo que puedes hacer es reemplazarlo por su wrapper o su clase envoltorio que seria el objeto Float con la F mayúscula, como es un objeto si puede devolver null.

entonces tu método quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
package stackoverflow;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class stackUnofloat {


    public static Float division(){  
       Float resultado = null;     
        float num1=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el primer numero"));;
          float num2=Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el segundo numero"));;
           if (num2==0){
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error, no se puede dividir entre 0 ","Resultado",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
              }else{
                 resultado=num1/num2;
           }


       return resultado;
   }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Float resultadoDivision = division();

        System.out.println("El resultado de la division es:" + resultadoDivision);
    }

}
```

El único cambio que le hice a tu método es agregar la clase Float y definir la variable resultado como objeto Float, num1 y num2 como float primitivo.

Dentro del Main nombre una variable resultadoDivision en la cual hago la llamada a tu método y tomo el valor devuelto de la división.

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa en lugar de regresar valores null es usar la clase [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) asi podremos hacer una validacion de nuestra variable antes de realizar cualquier operacion.

```
public class Snippet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Optional<Float> myVar = someOperation(4, 0);
        if (myVar.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("The value is %d", myVar.get()));
        } else {
            System.out.println("The operation is not valid");
        }

    }

    public static Optional<Float> someOperation(int a, int b) {
        if (b != 0) {
            float result = a / b;
            return Optional.of(result);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

PD: Optional solo esta soportado en java 8 o en adelante.